# Can't change video's opacity in reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I would like to add some green opacity to my react video, but fail to to do.
I tried with adding `background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)` to each of the divs, but nothing is helping me out.

Using the latest version of Chrome.

Can someone help me out with this?

Here is my code:

```
<div className="intro__video fadeIn">
    <video className="intro__video__content" autoPlay muted loop>
        <source src={bgVideo} type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="img/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
        Your browser is not supported!
    </video>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
intro__video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: .15;

        overflow: hidden;

        &__content {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            // opacity: .85;
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
        }
    }
}
```

with the commented out `opacity` it works. But `background` does not. Why?

Comment: That's not valid CSS; it's likely SCSS or LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opacity describes how opaque the whole element is: Including its descendants and content.

The background-colour describes the colour in the background of the element. The descendants and content are rendered **on top** of it.

If you want to use a background colour to shade an element, you have to set the background colour on something **in front** of the content you want to shade.

You might want to look at [SVG filters](https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/) instead.

Comment: Thank you, that is exacly, what I just found out, but you were quicker :-).

So to add the opacity to the video I need to write the background-color attribute in the parent <div>.